# Sequlize.js how to get the records count inside an 'INCLUDE' clause

Tags: sequelize.js

According to the **documentation** sequlize has a way to get the records count like this,

```
Project.count().then(c => {
  console.log("There are " + c + " projects!")
})
```

But in my case I want to get records counts inside the `include` clause.

I have two tables.

1. items
2. ratings

**A item has many ratings.**

**A rating is belongs to an item.**

This query will out put the items along with the ratings.

```
const dataSet = await db.restaurant_items.findAll({
raw: true,
include: [{
                model: db.ratings,
                as: 'rates',
        }]
})
```

But what I want is to say Item A has 10 ratings, Item B has 25 ratings like that

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

With include you can do that like  :

```
db.restaurant_items.findAll({
raw: true,
    include: [{
        model: db.ratings,
        as: 'rates',
        attributes : [ 
                        'project_id' ,  // <-- Reference key to parent table
                        [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("data_id")), "historyModelCount"] 
                    ],
        separate:true, // <---- Magic is here
        limit : 1 
    }]
})
```

Comment: Vivek could you please explain the logic here. =) Is "data_id" the PK of the ratings table and what is "project_id"?

Comment: @PathumSamararathna , project_id ( I think parent model in which you will include this model is Project so I used project_id )

Comment: Dear Vivek I think my question was unclear. I updated the question. Could you please look into that. =)

Comment: @VivekDoshi Doesn't you should use GROUP BY if using COUNT with another field?

Comment: @Blackjack, I am limiting data to 1, so no need of gruopBy here, or else it would be needed

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean how if take out the limit. Does we should use GROUP BY? I've the same issue but without limit, and give me error GROUP BY